IQueryable of different Types
I have an IQueryable that I add Where clauses to according to search parameters. At the moment, this queries the database so is of type Music (IQueryable<Music>).
I have realised that I have a cache of the approved rows of this data (i.e. where the rows have the approved flag set to true).
So to be more efficient, I thought I would to search the cache rather than the database. The cache hold the same records but they have been converted to DTOs so would be an IQueryable<MusicDTO>.
I have tried this:
if (search.Approved == true)
{
    IQueryable<MusicDTO> query = Cache.regetCachedMusics().AsQueryable();
}
else
{
    IQueryable<Music> query = DBContext.Musics;
}

if (search.ID.HasValue) 
    query = query.Where(x => x.ID == search.ID); //There are more of these

This doesn't allow me to add the where clause as it says the query doesn't exist.
So I tried:
IQueryable<dynamic> query;

if (search.Approved == true)
{
    query = Cache.regetCachedMusics().AsQueryable();
}
else
{
    query = DBContext.Musics;
}

if (search.ID.HasValue) 
    query = query.Where(x => x.ID == search.ID); //There are more of these

But this doesn't work because the x.ID == Search.ID throws

An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Is this possible somehow, or is it more hassle than it's worth?

Hi @steve!  Be careful on this site when putting bare angle brackets without using code markdown.  The markdown editor will interpret them as HTML tags.  I fixed for you but you might want to examine the edit history to see what I fixed and what it looked like before.  Basically without special markdown IQueriable<Music> looks like IQueriable because <Music> gets treated as HTML (that doesn't do anything).  So make use of backticks or escape your angle brackets with entities.

Thanks!! Put the rest in a block and missed that one :)

Typo alert : it's IQueryable (based on a "query" , with a "y") - not an IQueriable (with an "i") ...

If code must be structured this way, you could create an interface that has an ID property, like so:
public interface IMusic
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

If both Music and MusicDTO implement this interface, you could do like so:
IQueryable<IMusic> query;

if (search.Approved)
{
    query = Cache.regetCachedMusics().AsQueryable();
}
else
{
    query = DBContext.Musics;
}

if (search.ID.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.ID == search.ID);
}

